# Is it possible to get the name of the variable of a value in python?

Tags: python

For instance, let's say I have a variable named `D` with a value of `3`.

```py
D = 3
```

Is it possible to get the name of the variable `D`, with just knowing the value of it, which is 3?

```py
with(3) # get name of variable (pseudo code of what I need to do)
```

Does that make sense? Is that possible?

Assume that this is a global variable, don't worry about the scope.

I tried to see if anyone else has asked this and no one else has.

Comment: Seems a bit XY.  What is the use case here? I might be possible to hunt down the variable by value using `globals()`; but what if the value is not unique?  There is very likely a more robust solution.  Use case please …

Comment: @S3DEV, not a real use case, but was just wondering if this was possible.

Comment: No.  Python objects are all anonymous.  There can be names bound to those objects, but the objects themselves have no idea who is holding references to them.

Comment: You can search `globals()` for all the keys that have 3 as a value. `[var for var, val in globals() if val == 3]`

Comment: The issue with finding a variable by value is that what if multiple variables have the same value? How do you decide which one you want? Depending on what your trying to do there probably a solution besides this.

Comment: If you need dynamic names you should be using a dictionary, not variables.

Comment: In a freshly opened Python session, there exist 39 references to the `int` value 3, without assigning it to any names to start. So which reference would you want?

Comment: what if the `looking_for` object (remember everything is object) is inside a container like list, tuple. etc. i.e. bunch of "anonymous" objects. Not to mention generators, i.e. object is potentially accessible lazily.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.
Should you do it?
Definitely not.

All variables in Python are kept in namespaces, that in easier or tougher ways, can be viewed as dictionaries (mappings, more accuratlly).
Once you get to the proper dictionary, just iterate through it and compare the values with the one you desire.

For a global variable in the current module, it is simple - for arbitrarily placed references, one can make use of the garbage collector module (`gc`) and retrieve all references to a given object - it can get a lot of edge-cases, but it is feasible. (in this case you need to have a reference to *the* instance you want to locate, not just an equivalent value that would compare equal).

Getting back to a global variable in the current module:

```
looking_for = 3
for name, value in globals().items():
    if value == looking_for:
        print(f"{value} is stored in the variable {name!r}")
```

again: there is no reason to do that in "real world" code except if you are writing a debugger - it can be a nice toy to learn more about the language, though.

Comment: That's assuming it's a global variable, and that the particular value forms an equivalence class by itself. (Consider `1` and `True`: equal, but given `looking_for = 1` and `D = True`, would you want your loop to report `D` as a match?)

Comment: I am afraid that the fact the snippet applies to global variables in the current module is pretty explicit in the text answer, even twice. And this is is a short begiiner answer, that should not be expected to explain `==` in details - although it _does_ cover the fact that identity ("is") will be of more use - I didn't want to go down into explaining the fact that "3 is 3 -> True` should not be relied on.

Comment: Perhaps the fact that there *are* relevant differences between `==` and `is` means this is *not* a good answer for beginners?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dir()` without any parameters to have it return every single property and method and then iterate looking for anything that evals to 3. This just feels like a bad idea though, so I would reconsider whatever problem you encountered that led you to thinking this is a solution.

```
a = "foo"
b = "bar"
c = [1,2,3]
d = 3
e = {1:"a",2:"b"}


#grab a list of variables in play
all_variables = dir()

#iterate over variables
for name in all_variables:
    #eval the variable to get the value
    myvalue = eval(name)
    if myvalue == 3: 
        print(f'{name} is a variable equal to 3')
```

Comment: `dir` does *not* necessarily return every single attribute. It's not meant for programmatic use, only exploratory use in an interactive session.